# ColdFusion binaryDecode vs php pack(H*)

Tags: php, coldfusion, hmacsha1

I need to create in ColdFusion a 20-characters usable key from a 40-characters key. It's to calculate a HMAC signature.

The server I'm calling verifies the signature with the php package (H *) function.

When I try to create the key to compute the HMAC seal, I cannot calculate the same key as returned by PHP. Pack (H *) returns well 20 characters, but CF (binaryDecode ()), returns 18, some are ignored or the result is different. The signature is not valid.

Ex : If I try to calculate a 20-characters key with this one

> "325A16A325127FD42B700D4810E83F6312877B92":
>
> PHP return : 2Z�%�+p H�?c�{�, and with CF :
>   2Z�%�+pH�?c�{�

```
$key = "325A16A325127FD42B700D4810E83F6312877B92";
$test = pack('H*',$key);
var_dump($test);
```

With CF :

```
local.key   = toString(binaryDecode("325A16A325127FD42B700D4810E83F6312877B92", "hex"));
writeDump(local.key);
```

More code :

PHP.

```
function hmac_sha1 ($key, $data) {

    $length = 64; // block length for SHA1
    if (strlen($key) > $length) { $key = pack("H*",sha1($key)); }
    $key  = str_pad($key, $length, chr(0x00));
    $ipad = str_pad('', $length, chr(0x36));
    $opad = str_pad('', $length, chr(0x5c));
    $k_ipad = $key ^ $ipad ;
    $k_opad = $key ^ $opad;

    return sha1($k_opad  . pack("H*",sha1($k_ipad . $data)));


}
$key = "325A16A325127FD42B700D4810E83F6312877B92";
$validKey = pack('H*',$key);
$str = "7464052*08/10/2018:14:22:30*65.25EUR*AA123**3.0*FR*carmen*mail@gmail.com**********";
$sign = hmac_sha1($validKey, $str);
$test = pack('H*',$key);
```

Return: **23e7db20da9b58a47e27c151a65c2393a08ee4f5**

```
local.key = toString(binaryDecode("325A16A325127FD42B700D4810E83F6312877B92","hex"));
local.crypto = createObject("miscellaneous.crypto").init();
local.str = "7464052*08/10/2018:14:22:30*65.25EUR*AA123**3.0*FR*carmen*mail@gmail.com**********";
local.sign = local.crypto.hmacSha1(local.key, local.str, "hex");
```

Return: **ff8d510f348d1a9b3652b33b8e7780c9f8d4536e**

Comment: Ignore how they're displayed. The actual binary values are the same, both are 20 characters - or the CF arrayLen is 20. *"The signature is not valid.*" Perhaps the issue is with the rest of the signature calculation? What's the rest of the code?

Comment: It's not the same, see the space between p and H

Comment: I'm with CF9 for this project and I use de crypto.cfc from Ben Nadel to calculate HMAC-SHA1. https://github.com/bennadel/Crypto.cfc    local.sign = local.crypto.hmacSha1(local.key,'my text content', "hex");

Comment: The actual value is what matters. Both have the same length and both produce the same value when re-encoded as hex or base64.  So I strongly suspect it's just a difference in how they're displayed for a "human friendly" view.  Could you post a dummy example showing how the PHP and HMAC results are different?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try to search on that way.

Comment: Ok. One simple issue that might cause problems is that php's hex is usually all lower case, but CF returns upper case. Depending on how the values are used, it can sometimes wreak havoc with things like hashing..

Comment: crypto.cfc, return lower case in this case.

Comment: **Update** True and may not be the problem here, but ... it's good to keep in mind with any *iterative* code, since a change in case will alter the result - ex hash of "A" is different than the hash of "a"..  Don't have time to figure out why the cfc's handling keys the way it is, but ... if you change the functions to use type `binary key` instead of `string key`, the CF results are the same as php. https://pastebin.com/AddrhCqj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is combination of how you're passing in the hexadecimal key and how that [custom component](https://github.com/Kevin-Bronsdijk/kraken-net#image-sets) uses it in creating the signature. The code inside `_getMacInstance()`, which creates the secretKeySpec, manipulates the supplied value - and in this case - produces a totally different key. That's why the signatures don't match:

```
    var secretkeySpec = createObject( "java", "javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec" ).init(
        toBinary( toBase64( key ) ), // Changes the key value
        javaCast( "string", algorithm )
    );
```

*Technically* you could make it work by getting rid of all the conversions and just decoding the key from hex instead:

```
    // Create the specification for our secret key.
    var secretkeySpec = createObject( "java", "javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec" ).init(
        binaryDecode(arguments.key, "hex"), // Decodes raw HEX key
        javaCast( "string", algorithm )
    );
```

Then passing in a raw hex key

```
crypto.hmacSha1("325A16A325127FD42B700D4810E83F6312877B92",value, "hex");
```

Produces the same result as PHP **23e7db20da9b58a47e27c151a65c2393a08ee4f5**

However, you may want to modify how the component handles keys instead. So it's a little less brittle. For example, you could modify the hmac* functions to accept binary or perhaps even support different encodings by using `arguments.encoding`. All depends on how you intend to use the CFC.

Comment: Yes !... You are absolutely right. Many Thanks for you Help.

Comment: You're welcome. Nice 1st post, btw! Always a pleasure to help on threads like this. Welcome to S.O. :-)